# Meaning of set multiplication and right arrow

Tags: elementary-set-theory, automata, formal-languages

I am reading some notes as an introduction to automata and formal language.
The author uses the following notation, when speaking of string concatenation:
$\Sigma^{*} \times \Sigma^{*} \rightarrow \Sigma^{*}$

where 
I believe the cross means cartesian product of two sets.

However, reading up on the cartesian product on Wikipedia, it seems like the elements of $A \times B$ are ordered pairs written in cartesian form $(a,b)$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. So I am not sure if this is what is meant in the notes.

What would be the meaning of $A \times A \rightarrow A$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: $f:A \rightarrow B$ refers to a function with domain $A$ and codomain $B$.

Comment: $f~:~A\to B$ is a function with domain $A$ and codomain $B$.  Here, presumably something along the lines of $\circ~:~\Sigma^*\times \Sigma^*\to\Sigma^*$ was originally written which says $\circ$ is a function which takes two inputs both from $\Sigma^*$ and returns an output in $\Sigma^*$.  That is to say, you can combine two strings to form another string.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is what was meant to be written in the notes.
Concatenation : $\Sigma^{*} \times \Sigma^{*} \rightarrow \Sigma^{*}$ means that concatenation is a function from $\Sigma^{*} \times \Sigma^{*}$ to $\Sigma^{*}$, i.e. concatenation takes two elements (*in a particular order*) from the set $\Sigma^{*}$ (viz. $2$ words), and returns another element of the set $\Sigma^{*}$ (viz. another word).